# Persistent connections

Tags: php, sockets

I would like to create a locally persistent connection with my site.
I would like to create a single connection where I can exchange infinite messages.
I used the code below.
but it's really persistent? inside the "while" open (fsockopen) and close (fclose) the connection, but if I take them out of the "while" gives me problems.

```
$url="localhost/socket/socket.php";

$host=substr($url,0,strpos($url,"/"));
$req=substr($url,strpos($url,"/"));

$var=fopen("out.txt","a+");
while(1){
    $fp = fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if ($fp) {
        $data = "test=1";

        $request  = "POST ".$req." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $request .= "Host: ".$host."\r\n";
        $request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n";
        $request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n";
        $request .= $data;

        fwrite($fp, $request);

        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $json = fgets ($fp);
            echo $json;
            fwrite($var, $json);
        }
    }

    sleep(10);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: What problem do you have when keeping the connection instead of closing and reopening inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a persistent connection you should use `pfsockopen` instead of `fsockopen`. Look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pfsockopen.php) for more details.